# SQL query to retrieve all the professors

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables:

- Professor (EMP ID, Name, Status, Salary, Age)
- Course (Course ID, Course Name, PoINts)
- Works (Course ID, EMP ID, Class ID)

This is my db schema and from that schema I need to get:

> Return those courses that have been taught by ALL professors.

I have written the following query which is obviously wrong can anyone please help me as I am new to SQL.

```
SELECT 
    c.coursename
FROM  
    professor p, works w, course c
WHERE 
    p.empid = w.empid
    AND w.courseid = c.courseid
    AND p.empid IN (SELECT all(empid) FROM professors)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is called `Relational Division`. From your question you want:

> "*..Return those courses that have been taught by ALL professors..*"

Your title is  exactly opposite to what you want.

which this query will give you,

```
SELECT  a.CourseID, a.Course
FROM    Course a
        INNER JOIN Works b
            ON a.CourseID = b.CourseID
        INNER JOIN Professor c
            ON b.EmpID = c.EmpID
GROUP   BY a.CourseID, a.Course
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT c.EmpID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Professor)
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted. As far as I know, I've read the question and I understood it `:)` @downvoter, I want to know what's the problem with this so I can further improve my answer.

Comment: +1 such a nice question. @JW. just wanna ask(in curiosity) why have you kept **Status** Busy, because as far as i am concerned you are always **Active** on stack overflow and ready to help other. **:P**

Comment: @Luv multitasking `:)` actually it's an old status..hehe it's already done. That's why active on some tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
    courseName 
FROM 
    Course c
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
       EMP_ID 
    FROM 
       Professor p, 
       works w 
    WHERE 
       c.CourseID = w.CourseID AND 
       p.EMP_ID <> w.EMP_ID)
```